# IF condition in select my sql query

Tags: mysql

```
select if ((date_add(initial_time , length_of_duration)<=concat(closing_date, '23:59:59'), 1, 0)
from tablename;
```

I get syntax error, pls. can you help me to get the right syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an extra `(`:

```
SELECT IF (
    DATE_ADD( initial_time, length_of_duration )
    <=
    CONCAT( closing_date )
    , 1, 0
)
```

FROM tablename

Answer (score 1):

You're using more `(`s than `)`s at the moment