# Multiple condition in a single IF in select query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT IF(utc_timestamp >= DATE_ADD( initial_time, INTERVAL length_in_duration MINUTE)
          AND date(utc_timestamp) < (closing_date)), 1 ,0) FROM table;
```

I get MySQL syntax error, any one please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IF condition in select my sql query.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007847/if-condition-in-select-my-sql-query)

Comment: It is for multiple condition in a single IF, it can be a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a extra `)` after `closing_date))`

I highly suggest you using a editor like Notepad++, where you can highlight parentheses/brackets and it will find the matching close/open ones.

Comment: Thanks a million, you made by day.