# Is it possible to have mulitiple checks in a single mySQL IF case?

Tags: mysql

I want to write a query that will verify 8 parameters of a row are the same as the parameters passed to the procedure. If any one of them is different then modify a status, otherwise do nothing.

Is there a way I can check all those parameters in a single IF case? For example:

```
IF (v_duty <> duty) OR (v_current <> current) OR (v_frequency <> frequency) THEN

    * UPDATE ......;

END IF
```

Or do I have to use an `ELSE IF` for each comparison I want to make?

The above doesn't work, with or without brackets between each test.

Comment: are these fields in IF cases are involved into update query?

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want with `update`.  Of course, `if` accepts conditions accepted by boolean operators.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple condition in a single IF in select query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008503/multiple-condition-in-a-single-if-in-select-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably manage this with a simple UPDATE and WHERE condition:

```
UPDATE table_name 
   SET status_column = 'new_status'
 WHERE identifying_column = :identifier
   AND (
           v_duty != :v_duty
        OR v_current != :current
        OR v_frequency != :frequency
       )
```